# Why would I wrap a function in AngularJS $timeout service without a delay like they do in ng-file-upload example usage code?

Tags: angularjs, timeout, ng-file-upload

In most of the fiddles containing sample usage code for ng-file-upload (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) like the one at (http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/), the upload response callback functions wrap their code in a `$timeout` service call, but these calls do not have any delay parameter passed in.

The Angular.js docs for `$timeout` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) indicate that the delay is optional, but why would you want to make a call to `$timeout` if not to delay the code being run. In other words instead of the following, why not do the one after:

```
//inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
$scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
file.upload = Upload.upload({
  url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
  data: {username: $scope.username, file: file},
});

file.upload.then(function (response) {
  $timeout(function () {
    file.result = response.data;
  });
}, function (response) {
  if (response.status > 0)
    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
}, function (evt) {
  // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
  file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
});
}
}]);
```

Is there any reason for the `$timeout` wrapper in all these examples? Would the following file.upload call work in its place?:

```
file.upload.then(function (response) {
  file.result = response.data;
}, function (response) {
  if (response.status > 0)
    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
}, function (evt) {
  // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
  file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
});
```

Edit: I can see that it appears to run without the `$timeout` wrapper, but the fact it's included in all the examples makes me think it's deliberate, which probably means there's a security/robustness/browser compatibility edge case I don't understand here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's all to do with Angular's digest cycle. I'll try to demonstrate this with an example before I go on to explain what the digest cycle is. Imagine the following code:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'Tom';
    setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.name = 'Bob';
    }, 2000);
}]);
```

There's an inherent problem with this code. As much as we change the variable of `$scope.name` after 2 seconds, Angular is completely unaware of this change to `$scope.name`. If you now consider the following example where we use `$timeout` instead:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.name = 'Tom';
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.name = 'Bob';
    }, 2000);
}]);
```

Angular will call the anonymous function after two seconds, however, it will then start off Angular's digest cycle. This is the main difference between `$timeout` and `setTimeout`, the digest cycle being run.

The digest cycle is (put simply) Angular going over all of the watchers (bindings), checking for any changes and re-rendering where appropiate. You may have seen a mention to `$scope.$apply` elsewhere - this is how to start the digest cycle.

With regards to the example you provided: If the `$timeout` wasn't used, Angular wouldn't be aware that any changes have been made and as such, your view wouldn't update. I mentioned `$scope.$apply` earlier so you may be wondering why we don't just use this instead? The problem with using `$scope.$apply` is that you cannot be sure that a digest cycle isn't in progress already. If you do call it while one is occcuring, you'll see an error "`$digest is already in progress`". `$timeout` will only run after the current cycle and as such, this error won't happen.

People often use `$timeout` without any delay to notify Angular that a change has been made by a third party (like your file uploader), that it otherwise wouldn't know had happened.

Hopefully this clears things up.

Tom

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  However, as the OP explicitly mentioned, "it appears to run without the $timeout wrapper".  Can you shed some light on why it still works without the `$timeout` wrapper?

Comment: Also, depending on your needs, you may consider using `$scope.$evalAsync()` instead of `$timeout`.  Source: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: @rinogo I can only imagine a piece of code elsewhere is starting the digest cycle. It is impossible for angular to become aware of changes to `$scope` unless a digest is started.

Answer (score 1):

`$timeout` can be used to invoke any callback asynchronously. e.g.

```
$timeout(function callback() {
  // code run asynchronously...
});
```

This means that all javascript will finish running  before your callback is invoked. Adding a `delay` parameter to the `timeout` will delay the callback invocation approximately that much further, but you still gain asynchronous behavior whether or not a `delay` is provided.